# Rails receiving the wrong body

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with the following code that calls a remote service with a POST request and receives JSON data:

```
[..]
var options = {
    host:   REMOTE_HOST,
    port:   REMOTE_HOST_POST,
    path:   REMOTE_PATH,
    method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        // handles OK
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    // handles KO
});

req.write('user=myname&password=mypassword');
req.end();
[..]
```

It works ok on my OSX machine, but when I try it on a co-worker Windows computer, the data sent to the server is wrong and I don't know what could be causing the problem. The remote application doesn't receive `user=myname&password=mypassword` as expected but:

```
35\r\nuser=myname&password=mypassword
```

What could be the cause of this? thanks

**EDIT**

Seems like the problem is not Node.js Further investigation evidences that also my OSX box gives the same error when calling the dev server, while it works ok in production. Seems like a Rails problem. I'

Comment: Have a feeling there's a http version mismatch here.